# R .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'data.table'

Tags: r, data.table

I have downloaded v1.10.5 data.table and receive this error when loading the library.

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'data.table', details:
  call: address(x)
  error: object 'Caddress' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 3.4.3 
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) : bytecode version mismatch; using eval
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’
```

For clarity, this also occurs with 1.10.4-3, I have 1.9.6 working.

Comment: And what R version are you using?

Comment: 3.3.

Same error occurs in R terminal and RStudio.

Comment: This may be due to the old R version (the current is 3.4.3).

Comment: Have you downloaded Windows binaries or are you building from source (probably not if it says 3.4.3)? Note that the standard compiler (gcc) has been upgraded recently in Rtools, such that it now supports c++11

Comment: The requirement implies anything >3.0.0 should be fine.

I only really need access to the fwrite function. If there is an earlier version that works for 3.3 and includes fwrite then that would be useful. Do you know if that's the case/ where I could find it?

Comment: I downloaded the windows zip from the CRAN page, as the security restrictions in place here are tight and package downloads through R don't often work.

Comment: Maybe you could try downloading the **r-oldrel** version of the windows zip from CRAN and see if that works? (For me, version 1.10.4-3 works fine together with R 3.2.5 when I build from source.)

Comment: I am afraid using the r-oldrel also does not work. Same error.

Comment: It could be that you haven't unloaded the dynamic library properly before installing / loading the new data.table. Safest is probably if you stop / close your R(s) / IDE(s) altogether and then install data.table clean and fresh, afterwards re-open e.g. RStudio and then load the library without doing anything else

Comment: I think the issue is, the base R.3.3.0 install is on a work server. When we install our own libraries we install to our own directories as we do not have read/write access.

I don't think I can fully unload the old data.table library as every time I start an RSTudio or R instance it will have the server library installed.